# Spring MVC - How to display every row of data in CSV file on jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, spring-mvc, csv

I have a Spring MVC project that uses .csv files to store my data (for now the data are stored locally in C:\ in my computer).

My objective is to **display every row of data in the csv file up until the last one on my jsp page**. In order to do this I realize I would need both a loop in the Controller file to read data from the csv file, and a loop in the jsp page to fetch and display them on the webpage.

I have tried using a

```
<c:forEach>
```

in the jsp page, by appending the csv data into a whole string separated by row with a delimiter '|' at the end of each row and then fetch the whole appended long string through the model and pass into the jsp and do a

```
<c:forEach>
```

on jsp page, using 'split' to split them by the delimiter mentioned and display the data row one by one. The problem with this method is that each time I refresh the webpage, the same chunk of data will be duplicated and displayed and it just gets duplicated longer and longer.

How should I do this? Below are my codes:

Controller:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    String [] CurnextLine;
    String [] FutnextLine;
    String curdate;
    String curtype;
    String cursys;
    String curdes;
    String futdate;
    String futtype;
    String futsys;
    String futdes;

    String currentString;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);  

    @RequestMapping(value="/c_Outage", method=RequestMethod.POST)

    public String writecurrent(@RequestParam String date, String type, String system, String description, Locale locale, HttpSession session,  @ModelAttribute("currentOutage") CurrentData cd, 
            Model model) throws Exception{

        String csvFilename1 = "C:/temp/csv/curdata.csv";

        CSVWriter writer1 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFilename1, true));

        String [] record1 = {date,type,system,description};

        writer1.writeNext(record1);         

        writer1.close();

        return "currentO";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/f_Outage", method=RequestMethod.POST)

    public String writefuture(@RequestParam String datefuture, String typefuture, String systemfuture, String descriptionfuture, Locale locale, HttpSession session,  @ModelAttribute("futureOutage") CurrentData cd, 
            Model model) throws Exception{
        //CurrentData cd2 = new CurrentData();          

        String csvFilename2 = "C:/temp/csv/futdata.csv";

        CSVWriter writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFilename2, true));

        String [] record2 = {datefuture,typefuture,systemfuture,descriptionfuture};

        writer2.writeNext(record2);             

        writer2.close();

        return "futureO";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        String csvFilename1 = "C:/temp/csv/curdata.csv";
        CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename1));     

        while ((CurnextLine = reader1.readNext()) != null) {
            currentString += CurnextLine[0] + "\t" + CurnextLine[1] + "\t" + CurnextLine[2] + "\t" + CurnextLine[3] + "\t" + "|"; //appending each data each time the while loop loops
            curdate = CurnextLine[0];
            curtype = CurnextLine[1];
            cursys = CurnextLine[2];
            curdes = CurnextLine[3];
        }
        model.addAttribute("currentString", currentString); //This is the long appended string which is to be split in the jsp page by the delimiter '|'

        model.addAttribute("curdate", curdate);
        model.addAttribute("curtype", curtype);
        model.addAttribute("cursys", cursys);
        model.addAttribute("curdes", curdes);

        String csvFilename2 = "C:/temp/csv/futdata.csv";
        CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename2));

        while ((FutnextLine = reader2.readNext()) != null) {

            futdate = FutnextLine[0];
            futtype = FutnextLine[1];
            futsys = FutnextLine[2];
            futdes = FutnextLine[3];
        }

        model.addAttribute("futdate", futdate);
        model.addAttribute("futtype", futtype);
        model.addAttribute("futsys", futsys);
        model.addAttribute("futdes", futdes);    

        return "home";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/c_Outage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String c_outage(HttpSession session, WebRequest request, Model model) {
        return "currentO";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/f_Outage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String f_outage(HttpSession session, WebRequest request, Model model) {
        return "futureO";
    }
}
```

The jsp page - home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Admin Error Page Control
</h1>
<form name="hw" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td><h2>Main Menu</h2></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="./c_Outage">Input Current Outage</a></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="./f_Outage">Input Future Outage</a></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<h2>Current Outages</h2>
<table>
<h3><td> Date </td> <td> Type </td> <td> System </td> <td> Description </td></h3>
<tr><td>   ${ curdate }   </td><td>   ${ curtype }   </td><td>   ${ cursys }   </td><td>   ${ curdes }   </td></tr>
</table>


<table>
 <c:set var="input_ra" value="${currentString}" />
      <c:forEach var="ra_split" items="${fn:split(input_ra, '|')}" >
      <tr><td><c:out value="${ra_split}" /></tr></td>
  </c:forEach> 
</table>

<h2>Future Outages</h2>
<table>
<h3><td> Date </td> <td> Type </td> <td> System </td> <td> Description </td></h3>
<tr><td>   ${ futdate }   </td><td>   ${ futtype }   </td><td>   ${ futsys }   </td><td>   ${ futdes }   </td></tr>
</table>

<h2>Past Outages</h2>
<table>
<h3><td> Date </td> <td> Type </td> <td> System </td> <td> Description </td></h3>
<tr><td>   ${ pasdate }   </td><td>   ${ pastype }   </td><td>   ${ passys }   </td><td>   ${ pasdes }   </td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The currentO.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Calender Style Sheet Begin -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            $( "#datepicker"+i ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", firstDay: 1, changeYear: true });
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<%-- <form:form method="post" action="" commandName="currentOutage"> --%>
<form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="currentOutage">
<tr><td><h2>Input Current Outage</h2></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Date: </td><td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker1" style="width: 80px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Type: </td><td>
    <select name="type">
        <option value="">Select...</option> 
        <option value="Planned">Planned</option>
        <option value="Unplanned">Unplanned</option>
        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>  
    </select>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>System: </td><td><input type="text" name="system" ></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Description: </td><td><input type="text" name="description" style="width: 250px;" ></td></tr>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Current Issue"></p>

</form:form>

<h2>Current Outages</h2>
<tr><td>${curdate}</td></tr><tr><td>${curtype}</td></tr><tr><td>${cursys}</td></tr><tr><td>${curdes}</td></tr>
<%-- 
<c:out value="${date}" />
<c:out value="${system}"/> --%>

</body>
</html>
```

The futureO.jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Calender Style Sheet Begin -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            $( "#datepicker"+i ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", firstDay: 1, changeYear: true });
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName="futureOutage">

<tr><td><h2>Input Future Outage</h2></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Date: </td><td><input type="text" name="datefuture" id="datepicker2" style="width: 80px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Type: </td><td>
    <select name="typefuture">
        <option value="">Select...</option> 
        <option value="Planned">Planned</option>
        <option value="Unplanned">Unplanned</option>
        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>  
    </select>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>System: </td><td><input type="text" name="systemfuture" ></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Description: </td><td><input type="text" name="descriptionfuture" style="width: 250px;" ></td></tr>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Future Issue"></p>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Maven pom.xml file CSV dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For your information I am using Spring Tool Suite. If you want to help me you can create a Spring MVC project in the Spring Tool Suite and add the above Maven dependency in your pom.xml file. I have provided all my codes above.

Thanks so much for your help. I will accept the best answer and upvote the right ones if you can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pythonhiew, looks like your currentString is global, which will accumulate everytime you read in your file on top of your current currentString entry.

I suggest you move currentString inside your mapping and initializing it there.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        String currentString = null; //here
        String csvFilename1 = "C:/temp/csv/curdata.csv";
        CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename1));     

        while ((CurnextLine = reader1.readNext()) != null) {
            currentString += CurnextLine[0] + "\t" + CurnextLine[1] + "\t" + CurnextLine[2] + "\t" + CurnextLine[3] + "\t" + "|"; //appending each data each time the while loop loops
            curdate = CurnextLine[0];
            curtype = CurnextLine[1];
            cursys = CurnextLine[2];
            curdes = CurnextLine[3];
        }
        model.addAttribute("currentString", currentString); //This is the long appended string which is to be split in the jsp page by the delimiter '|'

        model.addAttribute("curdate", curdate);
        model.addAttribute("curtype", curtype);
        model.addAttribute("cursys", cursys);
        model.addAttribute("curdes", curdes);

        String csvFilename2 = "C:/temp/csv/futdata.csv";
        CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename2));

        while ((FutnextLine = reader2.readNext()) != null) {

            futdate = FutnextLine[0];
            futtype = FutnextLine[1];
            futsys = FutnextLine[2];
            futdes = FutnextLine[3];
        }

        model.addAttribute("futdate", futdate);
        model.addAttribute("futtype", futtype);
        model.addAttribute("futsys", futsys);
        model.addAttribute("futdes", futdes);    

        return "home";
    }
```